# Status Icon on Work List screen does not refresh

Tags: maximo-anywhere

When I click on timer icon on the Work List screen the status of the Work Order is changed to `INPRG` but the status icon does not change 
This seems like a `bug` because when I look at the element in the `chrome debugger` the path of the image is wrong and it is referring to the wrong `data-resouceValue`
When I look at the `image sr`c it has a part of the path duplicated ex: `images/mdpi/images/mdpi/statusicons`.

If I go into the work order and come back out, I can see the icon. 
I tried refreshing the view via `javascript` but the problem is that user is taken into the `WO` that he acted upon. This is just bad. 
I also tried refreshing the list bit it does the exact same thing ie: the user is taken into the `WO` he acted upon

Comment: This sounds like a bug report for a product, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug please open a PMR with details of your Anywhere version to get a fix.